# Why is my R filename NULL and not what I define it to be?

Tags: r

In this example:

```
nsims = c(10, 100, 500, 1000)
nsim = 1000
l    = 0.2

for(steps in nsims)
{   
    means <- data.frame(v=1000)

    for(i in 1:nsim)
    {   
        means[i, 1] <- mean(  rexp(40, l)  )
    }

    fn <- cat( "./means-", str_pad(steps, 4, pad="0"), ".png", "\n", sep="")

    print(fn)
}
```

The output for `fn` ends up being `NULL`.

Whats the problem about that? I mean I clearly define `fn` to have a character value.

Comment: Please post complete reproducible examples that include all library calls. `cat` outputs to the R console. and does not have a return value.  Replace  `cat` with `paste0` and drop the `sep` argument.

Comment: Or just use `cat` without assigning it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The R `cat` function outputs the value.  It doesn't assign it.  Instead, use `paste`.